# Fill data with NULL value if it is not present in the timeperiod using mongodb aggregation pipeline

Tags: mongodb, time-series, bucket

I have to write an aggreagtion pipeline in which I will pass:

1. Timestamps of start date and end data for a day

I have to divide the data into 30min buckets and find data in between that buckets like:

- 2023-01-16T00:30:00.000+00:00 ,  2023-01-16T01:00:00.000+00:00, 2023-01-16T01:30:00.000+00:00 and so on.

If data is not present in any particular bucket fill the values of that bucketa with zero but give the timestamp like:

- 2023-01-16T01:00:00.000+00:00 ther is no data give {timestamp:2023-01-16T01:00:00.000+00:00,a:0,b:0,c:0}

I have done the following:

```
[{
 $match: {
  $and: [
   {
    timestamp: {
     $gte: ISODate('2023-01-16T00:00:00.000Z'),
     $lt: ISODate('2023-01-16T23:59:59.000Z')
    }
   }
  ]
 }
}, {
 $group: {
  _id: {
   $toDate: {
    $subtract: [
     {
      $toLong: '$timestamp'
     },
     {
      $mod: [
       {
        $toLong: '$timestamp'
       },
       1800000
      ]
     }
    ]
   }
  },
  in: {
   $sum: '$a'
  },
  out: {
   $sum: '$b'
  },
  Count: {
   $sum: 1
  }
 }
}, {
 $addFields: {
  totalIn: {
   $add: [
    '$in',
    '$out'
   ]
  },{
 $sort: {
  _id: 1
 }
}]
```

Result is:

```
[{
  "_id": {
       "2023-01-16T12:00:00.000+00:00"
    }
  },
  "totalIn": 397,
  "count":22
},
{
  "_id": {
       "2023-01-16T01:30:00.000+00:00"
    }
  },
  "totalIn": 222,
  "count":2
}
...]
```

expected result:

```
[{
  "_id": {
       "2023-01-16T12:00:00.000+00:00"
    }
  },
  "totalIn": 397,
  "count":22
},
{
  "_id": {
       "2023-01-16T12:30:00.000+00:00"
    }
  },
  "totalIn": 0,
  "count":0
},
{
  "_id": {
       "2023-01-16T01:00:00.000+00:00"
    }
  },
  "totalIn": 0,
  "count":0
},
{
  "_id": {
       "2023-01-16T12:00:00.000+00:00"
    }
  },
  "totalIn": 222,
  "count":2
}
...]
```

Answer (score 0):

One option is to use `$range` with `$dateAdd`:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {$match: {timestamp: {
        $gte: startDate,
        $lt: endDate
  }}},
  {$group: {
      _id: {$dateTrunc: {date: "$timestamp", unit: "minute", binSize: 30}},
      in: {$sum: "$a"},
      out: {$sum: "$b"},
      count: {$sum: 1}
  }},
  {$group: {
      _id: 0,
      data: {$push: {
          timestamp: "$_id",
          totalIn: {$add: ["$in", "$out"]},
          count: "$count"
      }}
  }},
  {$project: {
      _id: 0, data: 1,
      bins: {$map: {
          input: {$range: [
               0,
               {$multiply: [
                  {$dateDiff: {
                      startDate: startDate,
                      endDate: endDate,
                      unit: "hour"
                  }},
                  2
              ]}
          ]},
          in: {$dateAdd: {
              startDate: startDate,
              unit: "minute",
              amount: {$multiply: ["$$this", 30]}
          }}
      }}
  }},
  {$unwind: "$bins"},
  {$set: {data: {$filter: {
          input: "$data",
          cond: {$eq: ["$bins", "$$this.timestamp"]}
  }}}},
  {$project: {
      _id: "$bins",
      count: {$ifNull: [{$first: "$data.count"}, 0]},
      totalIn: {$ifNull: [{$first: "$data.totalIn"}, 0]}
  }}
])
```

See how it works on the [playground example](https://mongoplayground.net/p/YnAueMQbHmY)

Comment: startDate can be - ISODate("2023-01-16T00:00:00.000Z"),
endDate can be - ISODate("2022-01-16T00:00:00.000Z")
timestamp can be any thing 
in range it is static data for 1 day

Comment: The answer support this, as you can see on the playground example

Comment: the answer will give only 48 document, I want the document to be according to start and end date, like if srart date is 1feb and end date be datetime.now() the it should create buckets 96 buckets of 30 min interval

Comment: One day (24h) is 48 documents. If you want less or more it is not a problem